# Writing generic function in F# to save csv files

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data

I have a requirement to read a csv file and generate several different projections of the data from save to files. I'm using `CsvProvider` to read the file and then map the data into other CsvProviders which I save to disk. Currently I have seperate save functions to save each of these projections. I'm wondering if I could create a generic `saveCsv` function like this?

```
let saveCsv<'a when 'a :> CsvProvider> (csvType:'a) fileName data =
    let csv = new csvType(data)
    csv.Save(fileName)
```

I can't seem to get the type constraint correct and also how do I new up a instance of the csvtype?

Comment: Since CSV files are text files, why don't you write a function that takes a `string` as input and saves that `string` to a file? If you have extremely large files, you can use `string seq` instead (for rows), or even `char seq`, for lazy evaluation.

Comment: Maybe CsvFile is better suited for you? Can you see if any of these are relevant for you: [CsvProvider1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315903/f-csvtypeprovider-extracting-the-same-columns-from-slightly-different-csv-files) and [CsvProvider2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551811/can-a-type-provider-be-passed-into-a-function-as-a-parameter). I'm not following your last question, but if you already have, let's say a CsvFileA type, you can you use its .Row(_) method to map over your data. Then you can just `new CsvFileA(rows)`.